# Will this force a reinitialize in Merge Replication Topology?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, merge-replication

I need to add a couple of columns to a table that is a part of a replication set.  It is not a constraint coulumn or a part of any article filters and it allows NULL.  I have a pretty good idea that I can run this --> `ALTER TABLE tblPlanDomain ADD ReportWageES VARCHAR (100) NULL`

and NOT force all my clients to ***reinitialize*** but I was hoping for some reassurance.  Can anyone verify this one way or the other for me?

Thanks,

---

Edit: Addtnl Info

This is what I am talking about --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870.aspx

It would seem, based on that, that the answer to my question is **NO** but I would still like a human confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nah the schema changes will be replicated. It won't force the subscription to re-initalize. The clients are all sql server 2005, right?

You should probably check that replication schema changes are set to true for the publication.

I also tested this in my lab environment on sql server 2005 to be sure.  You should really set one up, instead of relying on other persons.

Comment: Yes they are all 2005's and I am replicating schema changes.  I agree, about the lab enviro, I am just having difficulty simulating our subscribers.  I have a "Stage" Publisher/Distributor that houses the same data but I am the only subscriber and even that kind of sucks since I have to `DELETE` all my local DB's every time I switch from one enviro to another.  Due to the fact that the DB's have the same name.  Maybe I could create a couple of VM subscribers.  Thanks for the confirmation though, much appreciated!

Comment: setup another instance on the same box & you can have another subscriber :)

Answer (score 0):

With MERGE replication, I believe this will force a reinitialization of the subscription.  This is not the case for transactional or snapshot replication.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188063.aspx

Comment: @Brian Knight: I am confused...that article is talking about partitioning my publication using a stored procedure.  I would just like to add a non identity column to a table and not have it cause a reinitialize.  See my Edit for a link.